# Are these graph non-isomorphic?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Graph $A$

[image]

Graph $B$

[image]

Please are these graph non isomorphic? and what is the main reason?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried counting the number of edges from each node?

Comment: The count of edges are same in both graph. Count is $16$. Graph $A$ and $B$ are same degree vertices. So only one possibility how to determine non-isomorphic is exploration subgraph. But it this case I am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both graph's there are only 1 vertex of degree 2 and 1 vertex of degree 6.

In picture 2 degree of vertex 1 is 2 and degree of vertex 7 is 6. And they are connecting by a path. Whereas in picture 1 vertex 1 has degree 6 and vertex 8 has degree 2, but they are not connecting by an edge.

So these two are not isomorphic.

Comment: Ok I am understood. Thank you